# Docker communication to hardware on host

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to learn some things about Docker. Right now, I'm asking myself, if a Docker container can communicate with something like a camera from the host.

Can anyone answer me that, and say how to pls?

Comment: I'm working with Windows Server 2016. --> Docker on Windows not on Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Docker 1.2.0, you can use `--device` flag in docker run to access to host devices.

This is used this way:

`docker run ... --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 ...`

Comment: But he is on Windows. So that device will be in the linux VM

Comment: Windows Server 2016 supports Docker natively.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure whether that /dev/... stuff would work

Comment: Yes. That's exactly my problem. How can I specify the device without this Linux path? :)